# lowercase letters in CSV files

Tags: python, csv, lowercase

How can I input mixed-case words in my program so that it reads the `CSV` file and prints the correct solution?

In this case, I want it so that when the user types in `mY sOuNd Is BrOkEn` the reader will pick up the `sound` keyword and print the linked response.

```
problem=input("\nWhat problem do you have with your phone?\n\n ")
#Prints 'What problem do you have with your phone?' and expects an answer in the CSV file.
space=problem.split(" ")
#Splits their response into a list for each word used.
openfile=csv.reader.lower()(open("task2.csv"))
#Opens task2 file and creates a CSV Reader for it.
read=[row for row in openfile]
#Outputs the information from the CSV into a 2D list.

for x in range(0,len(space)):
    #Loops through the user input
    for y in range(0,len(read)-1,2):
            #Loops through each row in the CSV.
        if (space[x] in read[y]):
            #Checks if the current word is in the current row of the list.
            print(read[y+1][0])
            #Prints a link to your response.
            print("\nThank you for using GetRekt Troubleshooting.\n")
            #Prints 'Thank you for using GetRekt Troubleshooting.'
        elif problem==("Exit"):
            print('You have decided to terminate the program. Goodbye.')
            sys.exit(0)
        else:
            continue
            restart()
```

In here, the .lower() function doesn't work. Please help!

Answer (score 0):

In your current example, `read[y]` corresponds to a row. This means that `read[y]` is not a string, but a `list` object that represents a row.

You need to define the `read` as:

```
read=[[field.lower() for field in row] for row in openfile]
```

This way you have ran `lower()` on each element within each row.

Now to simply check if the keyword is in a row:

```
if (space[x].lower() in read[y]){
    ...
}
```

Comment: Yes this makes more sense, but still the program doesn't function and there is an error somewhere here:

What problem do you have with your phone?

 mY sOuNd Is BrOkEn
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\Home\Desktop\Nadim Computing\Task 2\Final\Task 2 Refined.py", line 102, in <module>
    main()
  File "C:\Users\Home\Desktop\Nadim Computing\Task 2\Final\Task 2 Refined.py", line 82, in main
    if (space[x].lower() in read[y].lower()):
AttributeError: 'list' object has no attribute 'lower'

Answer (score 0):

`lower()` will work if executed on the right variable. Instead of executing it on `csv.reader.lower()(open("task2.csv"))`, you should execute on the string variables.

Example:

```
# open using csv reader
openfile = csv.reader("task2.csv", delimiter=',', quotechar='"')

...

# compare strings using lower()
if (space[x].lower() in read[y].lower()):
    ...
```

Comment: Yes this makes more sense, but still the program doesn't function and there is an error somewhere here:

What problem do you have with your phone?

 mY sOuNd Is BrOkEn
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\Home\Desktop\Nadim Computing\Task 2\Final\Task 2 Refined.py", line 102, in <module>
    main()
  File "C:\Users\Home\Desktop\Nadim Computing\Task 2\Final\Task 2 Refined.py", line 82, in main
    if (space[x].lower() in read[y].lower()):
AttributeError: 'list' object has no attribute 'lower'

Comment: try `print(read[y])` and `print(space[x])` to see what object type they are. I think `read` might not be containing Strings.